# How to show list of Items in one Row Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
     ---------------
    |  __    __    _|_    __  
    | |A1|  |A2|  |A|3|  |A4| ...
    |  --    --    -|-    --  
    |---------------|
    |  __    __    _|_    __  
    | |B1|  |B2|  |B|3|  |B4| ...
    |  --    --    -|-    --  
    |---------------|
    |  __    __    _|_    __  
    | |C1|  |C2|  |C|3|  |C4| ...
    |  --    --    -|-    --  
    |---------------|
```

How to implement this in Xamarin.IOS with a remaining items show on horizontal scroll.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all that didn't work for you?

Comment: No, I haven't. I planned to implement Collection View for this but I think collectionView place items below when Row gets populated

Comment: Please follow these simple rules shown in help center for asking here in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use collection-view with flow layout. Enable horizontal scrolling.